# Opening Apple Help Viewer from web page

Tags: html, apple-help

From a link on a webpage, is there a way to open Apple Help and then show a particular page? Provided the respective application is loaded on the computer (and hence its Help book), is this possible?

Something like:

```
<a href="open-page.html-in-Apple-Help"></a>
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

No i dont believe this is possible but you can view a help book on a internet browser if you open the "redirect.html" inside the help book

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MacMan.